# PostgreSQL search for a table name in views code

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgresql database with a lot of schemas, tables and views. Recently, some 3 tables was replaced with one.

Now i have over 1000 views which may use these old tables. Checking them manually is little boring and easy to miss something. Is there any way to search for particular table, or better: schema in all existing views in database?

Comment: Your question doesn't make terribly much sense. I'm not even sure what you mean.

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462908/find-dependent-objects-for-a-table-or-view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this through `information_schema.views`, which is documented [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/infoschema-views.html).  Something like this:

```
select v.*
from information_schema.views v
where v.view_definition like '%tablename%';
```