# How to find the dependency between materialized views in Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, materialized-views

I am trying to find the dependency between materialized views. For example, in the below schema I want to know that `senior_high_salary_employees` depends on the view `high_salary_employees`

```
`CREATE TABLE employees (
    employee_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(50),
    last_name VARCHAR(50),
    salary DECIMAL(10, 2),
    hire_date DATE
);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW high_salary_employees AS
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE salary > 60000.00;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW senior_high_salary_employees AS
SELECT * FROM high_salary_employees WHERE hire_date < '2022-03-01';`
```

I tried to query the `pg_depend` table but I don't find entries for the above dependency. I don't want to parse the query definition of the views to fetch dependency since it's not reliable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find dependent objects for a table or view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462908/find-dependent-objects-for-a-table-or-view)