# Compare fields Where One is Similar to Part of Another in Postgres sql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

I would like to write a `Select` query where I can see if one column is like part of another column in different table postgresql.

**tblNames1**:

| ID | Description | target table |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | select test.fn_hierarchy_prod_group | test_1 |
| 2 | select run_update_query | test_2 |
| 3 | select func_datad_addr_1 | test_3 |
| 4 | select func_datad_addr | test_4 |

**tblNames2**:

| ID | Description | target table |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1082 | fn_hierarchy_prod_group | dba.l |
| 1091 | func_datad_addr | dba.n |
| 1099 | fn_hierarchy_customer | dba.m |
| 1100 | run_update_query | dba.j |

The query should return and update target tblnames1:

| ID | Description | target table |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | select test.fn_hierarchy_prod_group | dba.l |
| 2 | select run_update_query | dba.j |
| 3 | select func_datad_addr_1 | test_3 |
| 4 | select func_datad_addr | dba.n |

I am new to postgres and have search different ways to update it but I am not getting success.I have tried using query like

```sql
select *
from tblnames1 a 
left join tblnames2 b on 1=1 
where b.target_table like concat('%',a.target_table,'%')
```

But this query is wrong.

Comment: What’s your end goal? If those are view definitions, there are [system catalogs and views](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4462908/5298879) that can tell you which view depends on which tables. As to your query, it looks like you want to join on a regex with the `Description` column in it, not the `target_table`. Depending on where those `select` statements in the other description column come from, you might have a bad time matching them if they use varying case and combine that with varying double quoting.

Answer (score 0):

1. According to the schema you showed, you want to join on regex-matched `Description` columns, not `target_table`s.
2. You want the shorter `Description` with just the object identifier to be in the regular expression, and look for that in the longer `Description` with the SQL `select` statements in it.

[Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/Vj1uVPCX)

```sql
select a.id, a.description, b.target_table
from tblNames1 a 
left join tblNames2 b
  on a.description ilike concat('%',b.description,'%');
```

| id | description | target_table |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | select test.fn_hierarchy_prod_group | dba.l |
| 2 | select run_update_query | dba.j |
| 3 | select func_datad_addr_1 | dba.n |
| 4 | select func_datad_addr | dba.n |

4. You probably want case-insensitive [`ilike`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE), not `like`.
5. Depending on where those `select` statements in the other `Description` column come from, you might have a bad time matching them if they use varying case and combine that with varying double quoting ([unquoted are folded to lowercase, quoted preserve original case](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)) - in that case `ilike` will be wrong.
6. In PostgreSQL 14+, some view/routine/column dependencies can be found in [`information_schema` views with `_usage` in their name](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/information-schema.html) if that's what you're after. Some more insight could be acquired in the [system catalogs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html). [The demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Vj1uVPCX) shows how plain SQL functions with unquoted bodies

   ```sql
   create function f() returns text BEGIN ATOMIC SELECT result FROM table1; END;
   create function f() returns text RETURNS (SELECT result FROM table1);
   ```

   get listed in [`routine_table_usage`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-routine-table-usage.html). Unfortunately,
   it doesn't track those with quoted bodies

   ```sql
   create function f() returns setof int AS $f$SELECT result FROM table1$f$;
   ```

   so you do need to run regular expressions against the routine definition in those cases.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing ,I have created another question with similar details but some more requirements...can you pls help me with that..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78245542/query-to-insert-and-update-records.Your solution is really helpful and i am using it as starting point however I am working on building an overall solution because pattern of function like select *from function name will remain same so I am thinking to build solution by removing select*from and keeping function name while comparing exact match.